# ASP.NET MVC application to learn from.

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, open-source

I'm learning web development with ASP.NET MVC framework as I'd like to create os forum engine. Basic stuff and technology can be learnt from books but it would be useful to check real applications. Can you please advise good examples of real ASP.NET MVC solutions with good code and practices, interesting approaches to learn from?
I'm particularly interested in

- ways to create template (themes) functionality
- providing extensibility with modules, extensions
- REST API to be able to work with forum from external software.

Thank you for any help and advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic examples that there're on the net include [NerDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) and [MvcMusicStore](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/). You can get sources and explanations about them. But they're not enough for building real life projects. They're just good starting points. I would reccomend reading books - [Pro asp.net mvc 3 by steven sanderson](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043), subscribe to asp.net mvc blogs(those by Brad Wilson, Scottgu, Steven Sanderson, Scott Hanselman, Phill Haack and others), read about community tools - [mvc screencast series by Brandon Satrom](http://userinexperience.com/). Also, note that module extensibility, templating and REST API layer are far standalone things to learn. ASP.NET mvc integrates greatly with all those jQuery and http libraries that could help you in development. Read about [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) for extensibility. I would reccomend [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) for the REST layer

Comment: I agree with you. Reading books and articles on ASP.NET MVC, Ajax etc and checking some small applications, examples are useful. But I'd like to investigate real applications to learn from. Example  - Orchard CMS project http://orchardproject.net/ . It's very interesting to investigate their approaches to architecture, modules, their use of open source applications. I'm looking for anything similar. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: http://umbraco.com/ may be similar to that

Comment: I really wonder why this answer got downvote

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.com/).  Interact with the live example.  It's a bit heavier than an "Hello ASP.NET MVC" application

This is geared towards older versions of ASP.NET MVC so you lose some of the v3 features like Razor, but conceptually it would be a helpful starting point

Source code is available at [codeplex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com)

Link to related [Sample Chapter](http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf) of "Professional ASP.NET MVC 2"

Answer (score 4):

I second to looking at nopCommerce 2.0. Problem with learning ASP.NET MVC is that although there are lots of materials on architecture, tools and methods, it's hard to find and learn from a project that applies all the right architecture, tools and methods.

NopCommerce 2.0, released as a beta in this month, is one of very very few well-organized ASP.NET MVC open source projects. It has a plug-in functionality so that you can just throw a module dll to make it work. It has good infrastructure for dealing with themes. It has blogs/forums implemented. I read a post that someone successfully integrated with other systems such as CMS.

Since it is rather a large project, examining its code might be overwhelming at first, but I can tell you every effort will be worth.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Orchard Project](http://orchardproject.net/page) source code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Xenta Framework](http://xenta.net) project.